# Error in blockchain.info wallet

Tags: blockchain.info, transaction-fees

My problem is that I can not do any transactions at all because of an error.

```
BitcoindException(super=com.neemre.btcdcli4j.core.BitcoindException: Error #-26: 66: mempool min fee not met, code=-26).
```

I set the standard (not customized) transaction fee to about $12 now, but the error still appears. What is the way out of the situation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem of blockchain.info.

I'm facing the same issue and even though i've tried to set too high fee.

but it seems to be they have some issue and they will fix it soon (as usual).

They're service isn't stable at all. they get this type of issues from time to time and they fix it.